# Propagate properties to parent control C#

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, controls, propagation

Is there any way how to propagate properties from child control into parent - so I can access property like - `Parent.Property1` instead of `Parent.Child.Property1` ? I cant use inheritance - my parent cant be extended child type - its inherited from different class.

Also I dont wanna add code for each property from child to parent like:

```
public object Property1
{
   get{ return Child.Property1; }
   set{ ChildProperty1 = value; }
}
```

Maybe using reflection - something like this?

```
public PropertyInfo[] Properties
{
  get{ return Child.GetType().GetProperties(); }
  set{ Child.GetType().GetProperties().SetValue() = value.GetValue()}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just add properties to the parent class who's getters return the child property.  That's the proper way, you must have considered it.  Too many?  Exposing Child is the not-so-proper way.

Answer (score 2):

Without changing the parent not, but you don't need to inherit the child, you can just pass through the property:

In the parent:

```
public object Property1
{
    get { return Child.Property1; }
    set { Child.Property1 = value; }
}
```

Then you can access `Parent.Child.Property1` also by `Parent.Property1`.

EDIT: As you just edited you question to NOT want to do it that way, then back to "No, it is not possible."!

Comment: I wrote it into my question, few minutes before you :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's the very old design problem you're facing - there is no clear-cut solution to that in C#.
That's typically resolved by wrapping up child properties (as pointed out already by all), which could be tedious - or b) exposing a child, which isn't often the best way.
I wouldn't suggest the reflection as you don't want to do that really. Performance aside (might not notice that on small apps but if you adopt that style of coding it'd get back to haunt you soon), that's just resulting in a bad design, messy code and hard to follow, e.g. you don't know where and who could be using reflection to change some other part, or access - you don't want to do that to your 'own code' (in this case), only normally if forced into it, using other code - or in some situations (not rare, every larger bit of code has some sort of reflection in it but for a good reason) that warrants that, i.e. you have no other way of doing things, like crossing generic non-generic world, getting dynamic properties etc.

Having said that,
you could redesign some things usually to achieve something desirable in some other way.
E.g. by using interfaces and indirectly exposing a child - or moving things around so that the class that owns the properties is in the right place 'in the chain' when / where you need to use properties.
i.e. it's hard to explain this - as this requires a very specific scenario in mind and then a very specific solution - but normally you always have some sort of 'winning design' that solves those problems, and the fact that you're facing such a problem usually means..
1) you might not have organized classes in the best way for the problem at hand, and you're forced to trying to propagate the properties - instead of rearranging the responsibilities between the classes,
2) or you simply have such a situation that there is no other way around it :)...
... hope this helps some